How to change .esd files to .cab files for Win 10 interface language change?
I want to change the interface language for my PC that has Windows 10 Single Language version. According to a thread here I need to download the language package from uupdump.net and change the .esd to .cab files
I have used the script from this this github which created a temp folder with hundreds of folders inside but i have not been able to find any .cab file, it seems like i am almost there but i guess i am missing something.
Any help is really apreciated

Your script dates from 6 years ago. There's a much newer version of the script here.
